# showModalDialog easy alternative?

Tags: jquery, jsp

I'm currently doing a migration of my client's application and i'm having troubles with the showmodaldialog.

What I want is an alternative that don't cause to many changes on the application and easy to implement.

The problem is that the parent window has to communicate with the child. The child is always a JSP that has combos, text boxes, etc, and the entered data is needed in the parent JSP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jquery UI Dialog, you are using jquery in your application.

[jQuery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Or the other alternative would be bootstrap

[Boostrap Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

Answer (score 1):

Read this link ([jquery Dialogue](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)) for using Dialogue in Jquery. which is flexible and easy to use. In the link click on view source for viewing the code.